# Como colocar if e else dentro de uma função onclick para verificar se o botão foi clicado

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Eu preciso fazer um jogo de perguntas *sim* e *não* e a cada resposta eu mando uma pergunta diferente, como se fosse uma árvore de decisão.
Porém eu não consigo fazer essa comparação, pois ou o botão dá o erro *" Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')"* ou ele já vai direto para a última pergunta. Alguém sabe como posso arrumar o que eu já tenho ou melhorar ele?

Esse é meu código:

HTML:

```
<section>
    <h3 id="mensagem">
        <span>A maior parte do território do seu país fica no Hemísferio Norte?</span>
    </h3>
    <br> <br>
    <div class="botoes">
        <button class="button2" id="sim">SIM</button>
        <button class="button2" id="nao">NÃO</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
function pergunta(qual)
{
    document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = qual;
}

document.getElementById('sim').onclick = function(button2) 
{
    pergunta("Seu país faz fronteira com o Brasil?");
    
    if(button2.id == 'yes')
    {
        pergunta("Seu país faz fronteira com o Brasil?");
    }
    
    if(button2.id == 'yes')
    {
        pergunta("Seu país é a terra natal de Pablo Escobar?");
        
        if(button2.id == 'yes')
        {
            pergunta("Seu país é a Colômbia?");
        }
        else if(button2.id == 'no')
        {
            pergunta("Seu país tem o inglês como língua oficial?");
        
            if(button2.id == 'yes')
            {
                pergunta("Seu país é a Guiana?");
            }
            else if(button2.id == 'yes')
            {
                pergunta("Seu país tem o neerlandes (holandes) como língua oficial?");
            
                if(button2.in == 'yes')
                {
                    pergunta("Seu país é o Suriname?");
                }
                else if(button2.id == 'no')
                {
                    pergunta("Seu país é a Venezuela");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Identei o código e deu pra ver que o primeiro `if` está "sozinho"; dessa forma, o segundo será executado após o primeiro de forma independente.

Acredito que aninhando-o, como as demais validações, o problema do fluxo será corrigido.

```
document.getElementById('sim').onclick = function(button2) 
{
    pergunta("Seu país faz fronteira com o Brasil?");
    
    if(button2.id == 'yes')
    {
        pergunta("Seu país faz fronteira com o Brasil?");
   
        if(button2.id == 'yes')
        {
            pergunta("Seu país é a terra natal de Pablo Escobar?");
            
            if(button2.id == 'yes')
            {
                pergunta("Seu país é a Colômbia?");
            }
            else if(button2.id == 'no')
            {
                pergunta("Seu país tem o inglês como língua oficial?");
            
                if(button2.id == 'yes')
                {
                    pergunta("Seu país é a Guiana?");
                }
                else if(button2.id == 'yes')
                {
                    pergunta("Seu país tem o neerlandes (holandes) como língua oficial?");
                
                    if(button2.in == 'yes')
                    {
                        pergunta("Seu país é o Suriname?");
                    }
                    else if(button2.id == 'no')
                    {
                        pergunta("Seu país é a Venezuela");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, eu não tinha reparado que o primeiro if estava sozinho, corrigi aqui. Mas infelizmente o erro de "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')" continua, eu não sei o que fazer pois para mim a sintaxe está correta. Vou pesquisar mais um pouco para ver se acho algo, mas muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o erro que estava pertinente, mas agora o botão só funciona até a primeira pergunta, ele não entra no if, você sabe se teria como fazer para ele entrar ao clicar novamente?